# Configure Django to email logs

Tags: python, django, logging

I currently have Django set up to email me if an uncaught error occurs.  Is it possible to change the logging behaviour so that it will email me the full stack trace upon error e.g.

```
try:
     print 1 // 0
except:
    logging.error("I'd like to receive this as an email", exec_info=True)
```

Cheers,

Jack